# Meteor Keyup Event w/Regex Issue

Tags: javascript, regex, meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm trying to display properly formatted numbers in my autoForm input fields. The code below prints, as expected, to the console when I use a console.log statement. However, when returned to the client, 500000 displays 5,0,0,000 and .toLocaleString() doesn't work at all in the display or console. Any ideas?

```
Template.mortgage.events({
'keyup [name=cashOut]': function(){
  var cashOut = event.target.value,
  formatted = cashOut.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
  event.target.value = formatted;
}
});
```

Comment: Is it applying the regex twice?

Comment: CodeChimp, thanks! I think you're right, but I'm lost on how to stop it from repeating as I both grab and return the value from event.target.value so it looks recursive. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

The specific problem you're having is the use of the `g` modifier on your regex. I get what you're trying to do - comma-ify the value to make it more readable. A better regex to do what you want can be found in the accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript).